# Is there a simple way to refactor file indentation for a while code base?

Tags: indentation, automated-refactoring, editorconfig

I have a project which started with 4-space indentation, then switched to 2-space for some files only.

Now I have `.editoconfig` file to standardize the indentation

```
*.{ts}]
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

**Is there a way to apply this new rules to EXISTING code**?

Answer (score 0):

I found out [Resharper by Jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/code_formatting.html) does exactly the job. Unfortunately, available only for `Windows`

Answer (score 0):

We used ESLint for this purpose. We created a special `.eslintrc.json` in project root with this rules and used the `--fix` commandline option.

But you have to remove all other eslint config files from the project beforehand or you will get the rules defined elsewhere also be autofixed.